# How to combine multiple rows in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table `data` with 5 columns i.e. `id`, `genre`, `actor`, `actress`, `price`. In the table, there are multiple entries of an `id`. Since some of them are empty, I want to ultimately get one row per id.

Example (only 2 duplicates)

```
id   genre   actor   actress     price
5     a      NULL       b1        NULL
5     a       a1       NULL        $5
```

To achieve

```
id   genre   actor   actress     price
5     a       a1       b1         $5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  For instance:

```
select id, genre, max(actor), max(actress), max(price)
from t
group by id, genre;
```

This chooses one value for each column.  If you can have multiple values, you can put them in an array:

```
select id, genre, array_agg(actor ignore nulls),
       array_agg(actress ignore nulls), array_agg(price ignore nulls)
from t
group by id, genre;
```